# DB2luw: Export all tables from schema "RANS" to schema "TESTMIG1" within the same DB

Tags: database, db2, db2-luw

i want to Export all tables from schema "RANS" to new schema "TESTMIG1" within the same Database on the same server,
i dont have to use export import/load, no spicific limitations for what to use

already tried db2move with action copy but : *ERROR - The copy action does not support copy within the same database.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the stored-procedure ADMIN_COPY_SCHEMA

Documentation:  https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=procedure-admin-copy-schema-copy-schema

This lets you copy a schema and its objects inside the same database. It has many rules and pre-requisites so study the docs carefully and rehearse on a development environment first.

If you do not need the RANS schema (i.e. if you can drop its objects) then you can also use `RENAME TABLE` (along with relevant GRANT/REVOKE actions) provided you have suitable access.

For db2move, it is designed to move between different databases, or different hostnames, or different Db2-instances etc.

Comment: I cant get the ADMIN_COPY_SCHEMA to run, i have full acces to the system, rn im trying to do simpler steps, first just export all tables with data from schema RANS, but i already fail there

Comment: "already fail there" tells us nothing. Always show your code, and the full exact error message(s) and the commands used. Create a new question if necessary. It takes time to fully understand the documentation, so make sure that you understand every line.